# Bootstrapping anchor HREF in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an app that has a wiki style structure, loading pages via markdown.

I have structured my URLs such that `http://localhost:8100/wiki/page1` is a valid URL.

I load that URL and the page content is rendered. That page content has links within it that take the structure of `<a href='/wiki/page2'>...</a>`.

Clicking on those links takes me to the correct url (`http://localhost:8100/wiki/page2`) but displays the error "Cannot GET /wiki/page2"

Now I'm sure this is is because I'm trying to use the link as a standard HREF link, but unsure how else I might go about doing this. Thoughts?

Since the content is loaded dynamically, restructuring the page is not a realistic achievement.

Comment: Are those valid paths in your app's router?

Comment: Yes, opening a new tab and going to that URL works as expected. It's just when use the link to get there that I see issue. 

I've gotten around it by "trapping" the anchor clicks and using the navcontorller to push, but still an interesting issue academically from my end.

Answer (score -1):

In Ionic 3 you can use NavControl to navigate to pages

You just import the Page you want to go

```
import { SaleFullDatailPage } from '../../all';
```

and then add a

```
(click)="btnClick()"
```

to the html element

finally, create a btnClick() function in the ts file that has:

```
navCtrl.push(SaleFullDatailPage);
```